# PHP: Echo value from external link through URL

Tags: php, url, parse-platform

I want to make a pesonalization in HTML from an external Database for which I have permission to do so. The values will be passed through an public url

**Goal:**

```
Hello Peter! We have an awesome offer for you!
```

**Example (to show what I mean, but of course it's completely wrong):**

```
Hello <?php print $name (from http://html.net/page.php?name) ?>! We have an awesome offer for you!
```

I would like to have it as lightweight as possible and directly embedded in the body of the site. And may be an example how the URL should look like that I get.

Hope you guys have an super easy copy-paste solution.

Comment: What have you tried so far? How does this relate to parse.com?

Comment: Why not CSS ? but you need to provide more information, such as 1) do links have a kind of attribute/value ('sales', 'offer', 'discount', whatever...) ? how would you know it has to be linked to a particular user ?

Comment: @OldPadawan Hey thanks for your answer:

1) Will have attribute like "sales"
2) They get a link to their inbox where they used to be tagged with "client" for example. Then when they click on the link in the email, the page will open. I think the technique is similar to "when you click a link in the email then the form will be prepopulated already with your data" (just my thinking but have no idea)

Comment: then, if you have links tagged and users tagged, when you get links from the DB using the proper `select ... where ... clause` , I would apply specific CSS style according to what you want to achieve (ie: client/sales = blue or client/special offer = red ... and so on) don't know if it's what you're thinking about though

Comment: @OldPadawan okay got it. Could be an idea to go about it. I think it's tricky because I try to print value from an external DB that makes it more complicated may be.

Comment: well, this kind of trick is already used on many places : admin (identified as `1`) get blue links, users (identified as `2`) get orange links... just like for pages they can access or not, hope this helped...